# Retrieving a web3 instance from nextJs

Tags: web3js, nodejs

In my nextJS application, I am trying to create a lambda function that returns web3 object:

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
    // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
    window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    return new Web3(window.ethereum);
  } else {
    // We are on the server *OR* the user is not running metamask
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ADDRESS
    );
    return new Web3(provider);
  }
};

export default web3;
```

Nothing super complicated here. But when trying to use it :

```
import web3 from "./web3";
const ContractInstance = web3().eth.Contract(
  MyContract.abi,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTRACT_ADDRESS
);
```

It s returning the error below

```
error - Error: Please use the "new" keyword to instantiate a web3.eth.Contract() object!
```

Sorry if my question is stupid and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this syntax correct? `ContractInstance = web3()`

Comment: thank you. the way I was successfully using it before was ` web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);` I tried to put it into an arrow function for reusability purpose.

Comment: @johann you changed web3 to be a junction so you have to change how it is used `new web3().eth.Contract(..)`. You need the  `new` for the `Contract` object, not for `web3()`.